# netbeans IDE php 7.3.1 file disappeared from view

Tags: netbeans, drag-and-drop, window, taskbar

I accidentally dragged the tab of an already opened file to outside of netbeans. Now I cannot open that file.

This is repeatable pattern. Every time, I drag the tab of a file and drop it on say on windows taskbar, that file goes away.I cannot open it netbeans anymore.

Interestingly, the file shows on the project explorer of Netbeans.

Also, when I double click on that file, netbeans starts loading, but again, that file does not show. I end up seeing the Netbeans IDE - what's new - news and tutorials start up screen and the other files that I have not done a drag operation on.

I know it's somewhere hidden.

Do you know how to bring it back to life?

Comment: menu > window > reset windows fixed the problem. But I'm still curious, why this is happening?

Comment: The file doesn't disappear but it rather gets hidden as it thinks that there is no use of showing it as the main view.As soon as you reset window,it appears back as the main window!